# Getting connection reset error while querying from a view using date_sub() udf in cloudera impala 1.2.3

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I have written a query to create a view in Impala. The view contains a field record_date which is of string datatype of format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss. While trying to execute a query which extract the previous date record using date_sub('2014-01-30 00:00:00',1) , I am getting an error like this :

**Error** : Error communicating with impalad: TSocket read 0 bytes.

If I try to execute the same query over a table created instead of the view I am getting the output correctly.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, please upgrade to the latest version of Impala as it appears to have been fixed since 1.2.3, which is quite old.

This issue does not reproduce on Impala 2.2:

```
[localhost:21000] > create table test_ts_string ( x string );
[localhost:21000] > create view test_ts_string_view as select * from test_ts_string;

... insert data ..

[localhost:21000] > select x, date_sub(x, 1) from test_ts_string;
Query: select x, date_sub(x, 1) from test_ts_string
+---------------------+---------------------+
| x                   | date_sub(x, 1)      |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2008-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-01-01 00:01:00 | 2008-12-31 00:01:00 |
| 2009-04-01 00:00:00 | 2009-03-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-04-01 00:01:00 | 2009-03-31 00:01:00 |
| 2009-03-01 00:00:00 | 2009-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 2009-03-01 00:01:00 | 2009-02-28 00:01:00 |
| 2009-02-01 00:00:00 | 2009-01-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-02-01 00:01:00 | 2009-01-31 00:01:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
Fetched 8 row(s) in 0.22s

[localhost:21000] > select x, date_sub(x, 1) from test_ts_string_view;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| x                   | _c1                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2008-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-01-01 00:01:00 | 2008-12-31 00:01:00 |
| 2009-04-01 00:00:00 | 2009-03-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-04-01 00:01:00 | 2009-03-31 00:01:00 |
| 2009-03-01 00:00:00 | 2009-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 2009-03-01 00:01:00 | 2009-02-28 00:01:00 |
| 2009-02-01 00:00:00 | 2009-01-31 00:00:00 |
| 2009-02-01 00:01:00 | 2009-01-31 00:01:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
Fetched 8 row(s) in 4.92s
```